# How would I draw a circle using an SFML vertex array?

Tags: c++, geometry, sfml, vertex-array

For a university assignment, I need to draw various shapes using a vertex array, and one such shape that they have asked for is a circle.

I know that I would need to use `sf::TriangleFan` but I'm not super experienced with SFML, so how would I go about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Step one: find or reinvent the formula for determining the vertex positions of a regular polygon. Step two: Create triangles for each "wedge" coming from the center and two adjacent edge vertices. Step 3: profit.

Comment: Alternatively, for step 1 cheat and use `sf::CircleShape::getPoint` to have your points calculated for you.